# jQuery Ajax calls to web service seem to be synchronous

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have two ajax calls to a web service from jquery.

The first call (`GetMessages`) starts an interval in javascript (`setInterval`) and returns a string array of messages stored in a session variable.

The second call (`UploadUsers`) uploads users and saves the status in the session to be returned in the method `GetMessages`. So UploadUsers adds messages to the Session and GetMessages retrieves the messages and displays them for the client.

The problem is even though I call both methods asynchronously, `GetMessages` waits until `UploadUsers` is finished. It just loads.

I even put a thread.sleep between each user being added and I expect to have `GetMessages` return  "1/10 users have been added", "2/10 users have been added", each on separate calls.

What happens is `GetMessages` doesn't return anything until `UploadUsers` is finished and then brings all the text at once.

I have a lot of code so I don't know what to put but here it goes:

**UploadUsers.aspx**

```
callAsynchMethod('ClientStatusHandler.asmx/GetMessages',
'', printMessages, stopPollingError);

callAsynchMethod('ClientStatusHandler.asmx/StartRetrievingLeads',
data, stopPolling, stopPollingError);
```

**Site.js**

```
function callAsynchMethod(url, keyValue, callBack, callBackError) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: keyValue,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: callBack,
        error:callBackError
    });
}
```

**ClientStatusHandler.asmx.cs**

```
const string key = "LUMessages";
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string[] GetMessages()
        {

            if (Session[key] != null)
            {
                string[] messages = ((IList<string>)Session[key]).ToArray();
                ((IList<string>)Session[key]).Clear();
                return messages;
            }
            return new string[] { };
        }







  [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
     [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
      public string[] UploadUsers()
     {
    //This function adds a user and calls SaveMessageToQueue 
//for every user.
    //I see the message being entered into the session and 
//I call Thread.Sleep(10000) 
    //between messages.
    }









     private void SaveMessageToQueue(string m)
        {

        IList<string> messageQueue = (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.
Session["LUMessages"];
        messageQueue.Add(m);
         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have enable the Session and the Session lock all the calls until they return.

You can read also this question: [Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely/)

also read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660837/159270

Comment: I replaced the code in the GetMessages method to return a hard coded string array to test it and I still get the wait even though he doesn't approach the session.

Comment: @Eitan You need to turn EnableSessio to false (or to readonly)