# Increase in number of requests form server cause website slow?

Tags: asp.net

In My office website,webpage has 3css files ,2 javascript files ,11images and 1page request total 17 requests from server, If 10000 people visit my office site ...
This may slow the website due to more requests?? 
And any issues to the server due to huge traffic ??

I remember My tiny office server has

Intel i3 Processor
Nvidia 2Gb Graphic card
Microsoft 2008 server 
8 GB DDR3 Ram and 
500GB Hard disk..

Website developed on Asp.Net

Net speed was 10mbps download and 2mbps upload.using static ip address.

Comment: Is it database driven website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons a website may be slow.

- A huge spike in Additional Traffic.
- Extremely Large or non-optimized    graphics.
- Large amount of external calls.
- Server issue.

All websites should have optimized images, flash files, and video's. Large types media slow down the overall loading of each page. Optimize each image.PNG images have an improved weighted optimization that can offer better looking images with smaller file size.You could also run a Traceroute to your site.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This question is impossible to answer because there are so many variables. It sounds like you're hypothesising that you will have 10000 simultaneous users, do you really expect there to be that many?

The only way to find out if your server and site hold up under that kind of load is to profile it.

There is a tool called Apache Bench http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html which you can run from the command line and simulate a number of requests to your server to benchmark it. The tool comes with an install of apache, then you can simulate 10000 requests to your server and see how the request time holds up. At the same time you can run performance monitor in windows to diagnose if there are any bottlenecks.

Example usage taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench)

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://www.yahoo.com/
```

> This will execute 100 HTTP GET requests, processing up to 10 requests
>   concurrently, to the specified URL, in this example,
>   "http://www.yahoo.com".

I don't think that downloads your page dependencies (js, css, images), but there probably are other tools you can use to simulate that.

I'd recommend that you ensure that you enable compression on your site and set up caching as this will significanly reduce the load and number of requests for very little effort.

Comment: You can install apache on windows, you could probably then take ab.exe from the bin folder and uninstall apache, but not sure if that would break any licence agreements.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hardware, you should think about your server's upload capacity. If your upload bandwidth is low, of course it would be a problem.

Comment: It depends on how much traffic your server is getting. If there is too much request at the same time enough to slow down your website, improving upload bandwith would be first solution.

Comment: Caching and compression would be my first solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason is because one session is lock all the rest requests.

If you not use session, turn it off and check again.

relative:

[Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely/9021543)

[jQuery Ajax calls to web service seem to be synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052401/jquery-ajax-calls-to-web-service-seem-to-be-synchronous)