# ASPNET worker process stop responding when an asynch Process.Start is spawned

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In ASPNET Page I need to spawn a Process to do some CPU heavy work (ffmpeg) . I wish: 
a) send response to client without wait for process exit 
b) to do something when Process is done
If I do:

```
Process pc = new Process();
pc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
pc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDir;
pc.StartInfo.FileName = AppDir + "ffmpeg.exe";
pc.StartInfo.Arguments = ... some strings ...
pc.Exited += new EventHandler(handlerExit);
pc.Start();
// End Page
Response.Flush();
this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

void handlerExit(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(vars["path"] ,vars["filein"] + "*");
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                File.Delete(files[i]);
            }
    }
```

the browser correct receive response when ffmpeg is still running, but ASPNET stop to respond to every subsequent requests. When process exit,the ASPNET Worker process start again to respond. I attempted to adjust process priority start option like AboveNormal or Idle but without success.
Any ideas to manage this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to session lock. Disable the session on the page you call that.

Reference:

[jQuery Ajax calls to web service seem to be synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052401/jquery-ajax-calls-to-web-service-seem-to-be-synchronous/9052457#9052457)

[Web app blocked while processing another web app on sharing same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session/9427550#9427550)

[Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely/9021543#9021543)

Comment: It seems to me you've catch the right point but adding EnableSessionState="false" directive to the Page that spawn the process isn't enough because wp continue to be blocked. Maybe I've to take a more deep look to ASPNET Session State.

Comment: I'm convinced that is not a Session State issue only.

Comment: @alrama Yes probably is not only session state issue, the next think is probably open threads that runs your code.