# What perfmon counters are useful for identifying ASP.NET bottlenecks?

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, profiling, newrelic

Given the chart here, what should I be looking at to identify the bottleneck?  As you can see, requests are averaging nearly 14 seconds under load and the bulk of that time is attributed to the CLR in New Relic's profiling data. In the performance breakdown for a particular page, it attributes the bulk of the time to the WebTransaction/.aspx page.

[image: stats captured by new relic during load test]

[image: stats for a page]

Comment: maybe a delay to read from database with the standar session lock on the pages made this delay. As I see the orange is also up.

Comment: @Aristos can you elaborate on what you mean by "the standard session lock"?

Comment: I mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely  when you use session on a page this lock all pages until this page end processing because of the session data.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right. Session is configured to use state server on a another machine, and it's not flinching, db is not flinching, so serialized requests would make sense since the load test is using a single user/session. Time to spread the load among different sessions/users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that the database is readed also (the orange) and this is seams that one of all pages have delay the rest of pages because of the lock that session make on the pages.

you can read also :
[Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely)

My suggestion is totally remove the session calls and if this is not possible, find an other way to save them somewhere in database by your self.

Actually in my pages I have made all three possible options. 1. I call the page with out session. 2 I have made totally custom session that are values connected to the user cookie, and last 3. I have made threads that are run away from the session and they make calculations on background, when they finish I show the results.

In some cases the calculations are done on iframe that call a page without session and there later I show the results.

Answer (score 1):

In the Pro version, you can use Transaction Traces, which help pinpoint exactly where the issue is happening.