# asp.net runs fast then slow on restart

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-6

Why is it that every time the server goes down, and asp.net restarts, the response time is SUPER FAST when it comes back up for a few minutes. I assume because everyone is off the server and I am one of the few (or only) people back on the server so quick?

I have discussed this with our developers and they say the response time is due to everyone on the server normally (200+ desktops) and when you are the only person on there, it flys. Really? Then does that mean we need newer, faster web servers?

I am not a programmer, but I think there may be two answers, one is what the devs say above is true, and two is the system is accumulating temp files of some sort and they get cleared out when the server crashes and then restarts.

How do we prove who might be right? Where does one start to look for asp.net bottlenecks?

windows server 2003
asp.net 3.0
iis6
12GB ram

sql server 2005 (db admin says there is no load issue on sql..)

Comment: Since StackOverflow is a developer oriented website, chances are the response you might get here is that the developers are right and that sysadmins suck. No I am joking. By the way, Windows Server 2003's kinda getting old now - 10 years to be precise. Maybe you should start thinking about upgrading? I don't know, it's just a hint. Could get you occupied with an interesting project to well start the new year.

Comment: We do plan to move to Windows Server 2012 in a month or so, so that decision has been made.

Comment: Oh, that's really nice to hear. Good luck with the upgrade.

Comment: Actually you say here that you do not believe and not trust your developers, but you do not know how to argue because you do not know programming. From the other hand there is a serious of test and measure that they have to be made on your server to decide what is the reason for the delay - and actually you do not give any value information to get a good opinion.

Comment: I know how to argue :) But every once in a while you need a outside opinion in these cases. If this is a truly a load issue, then I would just buy a new server, but if this is a configuration issue, then that is another story altogether and more facts are needed. We do run New Relic (application monitoring) so that is somewhat helpful..

Comment: @Alex: Background: I'm a developer. "How do we prove who might be right?", run a performance monitor, analyse, assign blame. Believe me, after 15 years in the business, its nearly always the application at fault.

Comment: @Alex: Also, I've been working with ASP.Net since about 2003. Other than failing hardware, crashing a server is pretty rare.

Comment: @Alex: We ran stress tests with servers that could concurrently support about roughly 100 user requests/sec with no problems (dual core, 4GB RAM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some very basic steps that you can follow and check if your server work on limits are:

First you download the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from sysinternals and you run it to see two things.

- Is your server work on their memory limit ?

If yes then what program eats the memory, usually SQL Server 2005 use a lot of memory for database cache, and this is done after many time of work.

- Did the server use all of his computing power, if yes, check what program is the one that need all that computing power.

Now next step, download the [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) from sysinternals, run it and see how many connections are done, how fast, etc... There you can see anomalies, or if the computer is also on their limit.

Final step is to defrag your disks.

Also have in mine that the asp.net session is [lock the entire view on all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284530/asp-net-server-does-not-process-pages-asynchronously/12285168#12285168). So if you have one application on web, with too many users, and each user, or some users, make long time processing on their calls, then this can cause delay to all the users.