# Cpu cores per IIS website (process)

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, cpu

I've heard that only 1 cpu core can be used per asp.net 4.0 website in IIS 7. Using more cpu cores means entering webfarm territory (as a result session management should be done respectively). But I could not find any references confirming this.

So are there any limitations on cpu core count that can be used per website, where session still can be in-proc? Any references?

Answer (score 2):

Absolut wrong.

The IIS7 and asp.net use all cpu and the power of the server. Also include in that and the SQL server that run in parallel with asp.net/iis and also use all the cpus and (all) the memory. Also if you make any system Thread, you also potential use a different cpu.

What you have "hear" probably is the session is blocking the asynchronous processing of the pages that is not totally bad you know, is help in many case. Again that is not mean that is use one CPU, only that the calls on the same site are synchronous (the one wait the other)

Few words about the session. Personally I have totally replace it with my custom made session handler, but for any beginner site and small sites the current session is perfect because is help you to synchronize the calls.
Without the current session module, you need to handle the synchronization by case manually - that is not so easy. If you not do that, the results is usually double and triple submissions of the same data (all that from experience).
Now if you design your site for web garden, and design it good, you take care of the synchronization of the calls and make it work fast, and correct.

Read about the session blocking on:

[Web app blocked while processing another web app on sharing same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session)
[Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely)
[What perfmon counters are useful for identifying ASP.NET bottlenecks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056240/what-perfmon-counters-are-useful-for-identifying-asp-net-bottlenecks/9056650#9056650)
[Trying to make Web Method Asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325150/trying-to-make-web-method-asynchronous/11325285#11325285)