# Web app blocked while processing another web app on sharing same session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

Deployed two WebApplications in IIS namely /HRMS, /TravelDesk. Both WebApps are sharing session via AspState, the config information are

```
<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
sqlConnectionString="Application Name=Portal;data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ASPState;User ID=sa;Password=dev2005" cookieless="false" compressionEnabled="true" timeout="720"/>
```

A user is logged in an /HRMS Application, from that he is navigating into TravelDesk application on a new Window, the session is getting shared across the two web apps.

In TravelDesk Application, a user is trying to upload a bunch of information's, and it is taking more time to process the request in server. In mean time i am trying to access the /HRMS application but it is not responding until the TravelDesk execution complete?

do the session will lock in SQLServer? Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 the session is getting shared across the two web apps
```

If the session is shared across the two web applications, then yes this is the reason. The session is lock the response.

To avoid this, on the huge upload information disable the session (only on the handler or on the page that make the upload).

Relative: [Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely)