# Npgsql - complete connection blocking

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, iis, npgsql

I faced a huge problem with `ASP.NET` project performance which is using `Npgsql`. It does execute every query to database using single connection/database process what makes project unusable by more than 1 person simultaneously (database connection locking).

When I play with `pgAdmin` or `Dbeaver` `PostgreSQL` creates another process which executes my queries.

My connection string:

```
Host=localhost;Username=user;Password=pass;Database=database_name;Pooling=true;
```

Comment: What does the code look like that's creating the connection? That should be in each session at a minimum and likely on every page.. not saved in any kind of global area. Secondly, there may be a way to initialize a pool instead of a single connection, but I'm not that familiar with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Minimal speed bump was possible adjusting min/max pool size and after deeper analysis the main problem was caused not by `Npgsql`, but by `ASP.NET` session locks.

Details about that there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36753202/8458601