# Is HttpResponse.Write a blocking function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an Asynchronous HTTP handler and trying to figure out if the `HttpResponse.Write` function blocks until it receives an ACK from the client.

The MSDN documentation doesn't specifically say; however, I do know that the MSDN documentation for the ISAPI WriteClient() function (a similar mechanism) mentions that the synchronous version does block while attempting to send data to the client.

I thought of three possible ways to determine the answer:

1. Have someone tell me its non-blocking
2. Write a low level TCP test client and set break point on the acknowledgement ( is this possible?)
3. Use reflection to inspect the inner workings of the `HTTPResponse.Write` method ( is this possible?)

Answer (score 2):

Its not blocking, but can use a buffer and send them all together.

Try to set `HttpResponse.Buffer=false;` to direct write to your client.

You can also use the `HttpResponse.Flush();` to force to send what you have to your client.

About [HttpResponse.Buffer Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.buffer.aspx)

And maybe this intresting you: [Web app blocked while processing another web app on sharing same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session)

Answer (score 0):

HttpResponse operates in two distinct modes, buffered and unbuffered.  In buffered mode, the various `Write` functions put their data into a memory region and the function returns as soon as the data is copied over.  If you set `Buffer` to false, `Write` blocks until all of the data is sent to the client.