# Background worker with silverlight 5 makes wcf service calls stuck while running

Tags: wcf, backgroundworker

I am working with Backgorund worker. I have a Silverlight 5 application using WCF service.

When I call a background method it hits a service and this method takes some times to complete. During the time background worker is running, if i make some other service call it stops till the background method gets completed. I want to make parallel WCF service calls. I am not sure about the reason of the problem.

Comment: Show the code of what you tried.

Comment: Is WCF hosted on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF is hosted in IIS, then the most probable cause of your second request not getting processed until the first WCF call is returned is the [session lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session) put by IIS.

One way is to avoid using session for the processing or replacing with a custom session mechanism, as suggested in the above link.

If you provide more details about what your Background worker is trying to achieve, you might get a more targeted answer (i.e. maybe the processing can be done without locking the session).

Comment: i am using syncfusion to generate an excel and writing data into it fetching from database. this takes some time to be completed and everything is done at service sight, so basically i want to do is doing some other work till the excel gets generated. but i am not able to achieve this with background worker, service calls got stuck during the excel generation. Can you suggest some way?

Comment: Yes, but can you provide details about how WCF is hosted? How is the session implemented? My answer covers the case when using IIS and having a session, scenario which has the provided explanation.